# Why does the presence of the Global Interpreter Lock not prevent data corruption issues when using thread shared state?

Tags: python, multithreading, gil

I am trying to understand exactly what the Global Interpreter Lock (GIL) in Python protects, and what it does not protect.

An example code which demonstrates an answer to this question would be useful. I can't create such a thing myself, because I do not fully understand what state the GIL protects and what it does not protect.

Python has threads and those threads can share state. In languages like C, any many others, in order to access the shared state we might use something like a mutex, a semaphore, a condition variable or some other construct which provides synchronization or atomicity. Typically such things would be implemented by communication with the Operating System via system calls, which provides a single point of synchronization and control. (The OS thread.)

If I understand correctly, the Python GIL prevents more than one thread executing Python code - which is interpreted by the Python Interpreter.

Further, if I understand correctly, if we spawn 8 Python threads, then we still only have 1 Python Interpreter.

Those threads then become useful under two conditions:

- a thread has to go away and do some IO operation, which releases the GIL allowing another thread to execute Python code
- a thread calls into some code which is implemented in a language like C. In some cases this code will explicitly release and then later re-acquire the GIL. Numpy is an example of such a library.

I can't quite imagine why the GIL is not sufficient to protect the shared state between 2 or more Python threads.

Can someone explain this to me? A code example demonstrating why synchronization primatives such as a mutex are required would be very helpful.

Comment: The GIL is mainly used to protect reference counts. See https://realpython.com/python-gil/

Comment: Re, "...some IO operation, which releases the GIL..." Sounds like maybe you imagine the GIL to be locked over longer intervals of code than is the actual case. Any given thread will leave the GIL unlocked at the end of every single statement. I'm not a Python expert, so I don't know whether it could be locked and unlocked even more often than that. (It certainly _must_ be locked and unlocked many times within any statement that calls a function.)

Comment: @SolomonSlow You could be right. Following on from your comment the question which comes to my mind would be "if there are two threads running, executing purely Python (interpreted) code (not calling out to external C libraries) can those two threads execute simultaniously?" I am **pretty confident the answer is no** - as this is the whole point about threads in Python - you don't get the expected performance improvement with CPU bound workloads.

Comment: @Barmar I read the above linked article but the answer is no clearer to me. If the GIL is only there to prevent data corruption relating to reference counts, how is it that the GIL protects the contents of data - for example the contents of a list?

Comment: Re, "two threads...executing purely Python...code...can those two threads execute simultaneously?" They can execute _concurrently_ with each other. That is to say, both started before either one is finished, both in-progress at the same time. But because of the GIL, their combined use of CPU cycles in any given span of time cannot be significantly more than a single CPU could provide in the same time span. They run _as if_ on a platform that has only one CPU.

Comment: @SolomonSlow Yes - to clarify that is exactly as I thought it to be.

Comment: @SolomonSlow I think the granularity of the GIL is byte code instructions.

Comment: @Barmar It would make sense that the GIL lock is held while the thread running the interpreter is executing bytecode. If so - does that imply that library code which is implemented in C (like numpy functions) requires additional synchronization?

Comment: Further to that question - is there always a single thread running the interpreter, or in a 4 thread python program are there 4 threads running 4 interpreters, but a single lock which can only be held by a single thread? It's the latter, right?

Comment: I believe it's the latter, that's why the lock is needed. This is why multi-threading doesn't usually increase performance, because the threads are serialized.